# How would a debootstrap'ed system differ from a regular-installation system?

Tags: debian, system-installation, debootstrap

Suppose I perform a debootstrap-based installation of a Debian version onto an HDD/SSD, as described [here](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/apds03.html.en), including a `tasksel standard` to finish things off.

Now, the guide tells me that:

> You cannot expect this procedure to result in a system that is identical to a system from a regular installation.

Why can't I expect that (i.e. other than the fact that I edited some files manually)? And — what will be the differences from a regular installation?

Comment: When making a chroot environment with debootstrap, things like `/proc`, and `/sys` are not created by default. You normally mount these from the rest of your system.  Also, I think the kernel is not installed by default.  Things like `linux-libc-dev` and `util-linux` are available, but not the kernel itself.  Also the chroot does not run its own instance of systemd. `libsystemd0` gets installed, but not systemd itself.

Comment: "When making a chroot environment with debootstrap, things like /proc, and /sys are not created by default" <- Why won't the /etc/fstab file you write eventually include those entries as well? "The kernel is not installed"  <- Why not? It's a package after all, can't you just install it like a package?

Comment: Try it.  Take an empty disk.  Mount it.  Use `debootstrap` to create a `chroot` environment.  `chroot` to it.  `apt install` whatever you like (kernel, pid0, etc). Then try to boot from that disk.  This is effectively how an arch installation works (boot from the install medium, mount a disk, then `pacstrap` (which is a lot like `debootstrap`) to install a base system to that mount point.  It wouldn't surprise me if this is what the Debian Installer is doing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t *expect* the result to be identical because the process isn’t identical: while the installer does use `debootstrap` (through [`base-installer`](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/base-installer)), a number of steps precede that. These include partitioning, country selection, language selection, keyboard configuration, repository mirror selection, *i.e.* all the configuration steps which have to be performed manually after running `debootstrap`.

If you follow the guide you linked to, you should end up with a system which is mostly if not completely identical to one installed by the installer, but that can’t be guaranteed, simply because that particular installation guide isn’t maintained simultaneously with the installer. I haven’t checked, but I suspect the main difference in most cases will be in the disk layout – it’s unlikely you would exactly reproduce the partition layout set up by the installer (unless you handle partitioning manually in the installer too).

Comment: The question is asking about differences when I do actually follow the whole guide, not just the use of debootstrap. You seem to be saying that if I perform the - not uncommon - step of partitioning manually, I could well get negligible/indistinguishable differences? Obviously you can't guarantee that, but the impact is that the warning is just a warning, not a guarantee of difference.

Comment: Yes, I understood that you were following the whole guide. I am saying that the differences should be minimal, yes.